# Map specific array from largest to smallest reactjs

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I have array like this

```
const tmp = [{watch: 87}, {watch: 22}, {watch: 68},{watch: 24}, {watch: 35}]
```

The result what I want

```
87
68
35
```

So I want map array but only need 3 and sort from largest to smallest

Can someone help me how to filter like that ? thank you :D

Comment: @why have you tagged it with recactjs?? its plain javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const tmp = [{watch:87},{watch:22},{watch:68},{watch:24},{watch:35}]

const sortedArray = tmp.sort( (a,b) => { 
     if(a.watch > b.watch){
         return -1;
     }else{
         return 1;
     }
});

console.log(sortedArray);
```

The answer will be like this

```
[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  { watch: 87 },                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  { watch: 68 },                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  { watch: 35 },                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  { watch: 24 },                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  { watch: 22 }                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
]
```

The answer is an sorted array. So you can get your answer by

```
sortedArray.forEach(value -> console.log(value.watch))
```

You can use

```
slice(0,3)
```

to reduce the number of output to 3.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer using sort, map and slice methods.

```
const tmp = [{watch:87},{watch:22},{watch:68},{watch:24},{watch:35}];

tmp.sort((a, b) => b.watch - a.watch).map(a => a.watch).slice(0,3);
```